# How to handle events in extended classes?

Tags: .net, vb.net, class, inheritance, event-handling

When one extends a class, how is the proper way of setting code to be executed upon some event of the base class?

Should one handle the base class event this way:

```
Public Class Class2
    Inherits Class1

    Private Sub MyBase_MyEvent(sender as object, e as eventargs) Handles MyBase.MyEvent
        ' do stuff here
    End Sub
End Class
```

Or should one override the event caller sub?

```
Public Class Class2
    Inherits Class1

    Protected Overrides Sub OnMyEvent(e as EventArgs)
        MyBase.OnMyEvent(e)
        ' do stuff here
    End Sub
End Class
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I got and answer at https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/343769/234737 and post it here for record and help of others with same question:

> Both options are fine and common. The big difference: with option 1, you can't necessarily tell what order the handlers are fired in, while with the second option, you can decide whether MyBase.OnMyEvent is called before or after your overridden implementation.